# ASP.NET Core: Modal does not pass values to controller method

Tags: c#, html, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

My index consists of a table that shows all my created questions (a survey). But I want to be able to edit a question using a modal. Therefore I have created the following modal in a foreach loop:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Questions)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Question1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReplyOptions)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Group)
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (item.CategoryId != null)
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.Name)
                }
                else
                {
                    <i><font color="red">Nicht zugewiesen</font></i>
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@item.Id">
                    Bearbeiten
                </button>

                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="@item.Id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="xxx" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                                <h2 class="modal-title" id="xxx">Frage bearbeiten</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form asp-action="Edit">
                                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Id" />
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label asp-for="@item.CategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
                                        <select asp-for="@item.CategoryId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CategoryId"></select>
                                        <span asp-validation-for="@item.CategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label asp-for="@item.Question1" class="control-label"></label>
                                        <input asp-for="@item.Question1" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="@item.Question1" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label asp-for="@item.ReplyOptions" class="control-label"></label>
                                        <input asp-for="@item.ReplyOptions" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="@item.ReplyOptions" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label asp-for="@item.Group" class="control-label"></label>
                                        <input asp-for="@item.Group" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="@item.Group" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

But I have the following problem:
When I want to edit the question and click on Save, my Edit method in the controller does not get the values.
The method looks like this:

[image: Edit method in my Controller (while debugging)]

What do I have to do to ensure that the values are passed on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What do I have to do to ensure that the values are passed on?

Just to add **name** attribute to each control in the form :

```
  <div class="modal-body">
                                <form asp-action="Edit">
                                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Id" name="Id" />
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label asp-for="@item.CategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
                                        <select asp-for="@item.CategoryId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CategoryId" name="CategoryId"></select>
                                        <span asp-validation-for="@item.CategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label asp-for="@item.Question1" class="control-label"></label>
                                        <input asp-for="@item.Question1" class="form-control" name="Question1" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="@item.Question1" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label asp-for="@item.ReplyOptions" class="control-label"></label>
                                        <input asp-for="@item.ReplyOptions" class="form-control" name="ReplyOptions" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="@item.ReplyOptions" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label asp-for="@item.Group" class="control-label"></label>
                                        <input asp-for="@item.Group" class="form-control" name="Group" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="@item.Group" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
```

Here is the test result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much !! :D
But I would like to ask you one more question:
I also have a modal for creating a question and there it also works without the "name" attribute. Why do I need it in this case?

Comment: @Toasty, `asp-for` will automatically generate the `name` attribute, the key lies in the form of the name attribute. Your initial code name automatically generates the value of `item.filedName`, but the `Question` class accepted in action does not have an `item` outer field, so you need to add name attribute to override the name automatically generated by asp-for. The case you mentioned that you can directly transfer data shows that the name automatically generated by asp-for is consistent with the class structure received in the code behind. You can use F12 to view the rendered html.